# Intersection of linear and quadratic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I've been stuck on some math work and I'm not sure how to do it. It involves finding  the point where a quadratic and linear function intersect only once.

Determine the value of $k$ such that $g(x) = 3x+k$ intersects the quadratic function $f(x) = 2x^2 -5x +3$ at exactly one point.

How do I figure out the $k$ value?

Comment: @Gal that simply isn't true.

Comment: Yeah sorry i realized i made a mistake. Solved it like you but assumed something that isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the two RHS's equal to each other: $3x +k = 2x^2 - 5x+3$.

Rearrange: $2x^2 - 8x +(3-k) = 0.$

There is precisely one intersection if and only if the descriminant of this quadratic equals zero.

The descriminant is $64 -8(3-k) = 40 + 8k $, and this equals zero if and only if $k=-5$.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. I forgot about the discriminant. I understand how to do it now.

Comment: OK, that's a pleasure. If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget that it's possible to accept it :)